# При отправке запроса к апи SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, http, исключения, okhttp

На сервере софт мониторит и время от времени шлёт запросы к апи. Около суток софт работает просто идеально, а затем выдаёт эксепшн:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

**Как я отправляю запрос:**

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(String.valueOf(message)).build();
response.body().close();
```

**Пытался выставлять разные таймауты: 5 сек, 120 сек, 12000 сек.**

```
client.setConnectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
```

**Кроме этого, делал обработку этого эксепшна и переотправлял запрос:**

```
try {
//запрос (и со своими таймаутами, и без)
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
sendRequest(parametres);
}
```

**Также пробовал на всякий случай просто:**

```
throws SocketTimeoutException
```

Результаты всегда одни и те же: работа в течении суток, затем эксепшн. Около недели испытывал разные вариации, решения найдено не было.

Answer (score 0):

выставите таймаут в 0 и посмотрите что будет. Варианта, на самом деле 2: либо всё будет ок, и запросы будут нормально проходить, либо повиснут намертво. Если второе - мне кажется стоит почитать про то, как в OkHttp работает пул коннекшенов. Возможно достаточно будет что-то с ним перенастроить.